# How to access MySql on my dedicated server from remote machine

Tags: mysql, remote-access, dedicated-server, dedicated-hosting

I have MySql server setup on my dedicated server with an IP address 12.12.123.123 . I have configured MySql to allow remote access. Now I want to access the server from remote application. How can I do this? How will I get the host/server name of MySql to put in my connection string?

Thanks

Comment: You just said you have the IP address. That is your host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put the IP address of the server as the hostname.

Make sure that

- The mysql server is listening on the public IP, so in `my.cnf`:

  ```
  bind-address = 0.0.0.0
  ```
- The user you configured on the mysql server is permitted to access the schema remotely:

  ```
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO `user`@% ...
  ```

  To be more secure, you don't have to use the wildcard, you can use a specific host or IP pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your server is fully accessible and the server instance adequately configured, you can test the connection using mysql's `-h` switch like so:

```
mysql -u username -p -h 44.55.66.77
```

Once this connection has been made successfully, you can use the same details in your application.